# Cannot boot Ubuntu 14.04 Installation DVD

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation

After a failed upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 I tried to re-install Ubuntu using the DVD. No matter what I try,*Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu*, I get stuck in the boot screen. (I mean the screen with the Ubuntu trademark and the blinking dots.) Pressing F4 reveals:

```
stdin: Not a typewriter
unable to open '/dev/sdb'
Bus Error
```

I did check the checksum of the DVD ISO before burning and I even burnt a second DVD. Also, I tried the different compatibility modes (nomodeset etc.). No dice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I was able to fix and upgrade the broken installation that I already had. I will not mark this as solved though, as the problem would still exist would I still try to install Ubuntu from the DVD.

Comment: Did you do the media check on the DVD?  Might be a problem with the burning.

Comment: I didn't check with the first DVD, because I forgot, but I did check the second DVD with the burning tool.

Answer (score 0):

> unable to open '/dev/sdb'

Assuming that your DVD-ROM is `/dev/sdb` your problem is probably hardware related. Did you try running a hardware diagnostic? Check to see if that's possible in your BIOS before boot.

In the meantime, however, a possible alternate solution to your problem may be to use a USB device instead of a DVD.